# Create empty directory using sbt-native-packager universalPlugin

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

I'm using sbt-native-packager universalPlugin to create distribution. What I want is to define empty folder while creating distrib in order to fill it with configuration files later (during deploy stage. configuration is managed separately)
I tried obvious solution, but it doesn't work:

```
val confDir = ((baseDirectory.value / "src" / "resources" / "empty"), "conf")
(mappings in Universal).value :+ confDir
```

Fails with "file does not exist".

How can I create empty directory?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create this folder via the [universal packaging conventions](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/universal.html#universal-conventions).

```
src/universal/conf
```

Comment: What if it's a different folder than `conf`? One that's not included in the universal conventions.

Comment: Everything in `src/universal` is included. The answer just matches the question. You can do `src/universal/foobar` too